# Fit video inside of a view

Tags: swift, avkit

I'm trying to fit a video inside the view I've created on storyboard.

[image]

Here is how I added the view to my storyboard.

[image]

Here is how it shown in simulator. I want to fit the video inside of the view I've created.

```
func createVideoView() {
    if let url = URL(string: self.videoUrl!) {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        let avController = AVPlayerViewController()
        avController.player = player
        // your desired frame
        avController.view.frame = self.videoView.frame
        self.view.addSubview(avController.view)
        self.addChild(avController)
    }
}
```

Also here is how I create the video. Notice that videoView variable is the view I want to show the video in.

Comment: It looks like the `AVPlayer` is filling the full size, but the video isn't. Have you tried playing with the `videoGravity` properties of your `AVPlayerViewController`?

Comment: And / or how are you setting the frame of your `videoView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AVPlayerController` has attribute `videoGravity` to set fill video and `resizeAspectFill` is the one you need to set fill video on the screen. Notice that when you fill maybe it will not show correctly for all video.

```swift
func createVideoView() {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v") {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        let avController = AVPlayerViewController()
        avController.player = player
        // your desired frame
        avController.view.frame = self.videoView.frame
        avController.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill // here
        self.view.addSubview(avController.view)
        self.addChild(avController)
    }
}
```

Beside, you should make the `AVPlayer` as the subview of your `videoView` so that you can handle easier than `addSubView` to your `viewController`.

```swift
func createVideoView() {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v") {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        let avController = AVPlayerViewController()
        avController.player = player
        // your desired frame
        avController.view.frame = self.videoView.bounds // change to bounds
        avController.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill // here
        self.videoView.addSubview(avController.view) // add subview to videoView
        self.addChild(avController)
    }
}
```